# Shopify - Making an API request to update user's email

Tags: shopify

Using the Shopify Admin API - I've been able to update a user's email address.

I've tested it with Postman, passing in a private app secret key.

Now I want to have this functionality on an actual page however have some questions:

- I can't exactly store those private app keys on the JS code of the page itself as anyone would see. Neither can I make send a request with it as again anyone would have visbility.
- Is it possible to create some sort of intermediary where I could make some sort of endpoint like `POST /update/useremail` sending across a customer ID
- If the above is possible - I'm not sure how I could avoid any random person hitting that endpoint and updating other user's email addresses.

Has anyone had any experience/ideas/suggestions for a simply way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: Your issue is here that you want to verify if the email change request is a valid call or not? Then if you find it valid then you make the API call to update it.

**My Solution**
Create a page in Shopify with your form to update email. Show the page only to logged in users. When a user lands in the page show them the form to pass the new email they want. This where you need to add a few things so as to validate the requests. When the page loads create a hashed string from the Shopify Backend like below.

```
{% if customer != nil %}
  {% assign timestamp = 'now' | date: "%s" %} //epoch time stamp
  token = {{ customer.email | append: '<random_string>' | append: timestamp | sha256 }}
{% endif %}
```

Whenever a request is made for a change of email validate the SHA256 code at your end by creating a hash at your server. If the hash is valid update the email. Make sure you pass the timestamp and old email in the request you make.

Security issues you need to take care of -

1. You need to validate timestamp always For eg. It should not be 10 secs in the future or 10 secs in the past.
2. Your random string can also be brute forced. So keep updating the random string regularly using Assets API. It is very unlikely but why take the risk.

Comment: Hi - Thanks. Thats making some sense. A couple of questions, that `'<random_string>'` - I presume thats just some secret? I presume because that token is being generated before the page loads - if someone went to look at the code they would just see the token as a whole and not my `'<random_string>'`?
Secondly, when you validate at the server end - what is the easiest way to get that up? Create some sort of private Shopify app? Or just something like a node.js/express app? Thanks

Comment: Also you say `Your random string can also be decoded back even though it is SHA256 encoding` - how is that done?

Comment: You would require a Shopify private app to make the update email call. You would require to host the endpoint somewhere such as aws. At your server, you would then have to generate the hash again and compare. the random string cannot be decoded back. I have updated the same. But it can be brute forced. It is very unlikely though but it can be done.

Comment: Hosting the URL is not possible from inside shopify. You have to do the same yourself.

Comment: Thanks - using AWS gateway and it looks like the free tier would be sufficient :)

Comment: By the way - you mentioned `You need to validate timestamp` - by the time the message is sent to the server the time would have changed - so how do I do a check for +/- seconds?

Comment: Ah yes. It will take some time for the user to submit the request. You may try routing the user to another page and make the update password call from there so that there is not a lot of delay.